# Why does executing a set of tests give different results to if executed individually?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, kotlin

I have two tests. If I tell Intellij to test them both (i.e. test the junit class that contains them both), test 2 fails. If I run test 1 only, it passes. If I then run test 2, it passes. Do you have any ideas why there could be this discrepancy please?

I have told test 1 to wait 10 seconds at the end of the test, to roughly emulate the gap between me manually executing test 1, and then test 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely there are leftover conditions from test 1 that are still there when you run test 2.

Comment: Can you show the tests?

Comment: Looks like both tests modify same resource and do not revert their changes when they finish. Like test1 inserts record in database and then checks that only one record exists. Then test 1 doesn't delete that record. Then test2 inserts another record and checks that only one records exits in the table but now there are two records (one left from test1 and one from test2) so test2 fails.

Answer (score 3):

Without source code to look at, the simple answer is: your tests aren't independent.

Meaning: they are somehow connected through *some sort* of *shared resource*. Each test depends on that resource to be in a certain state, but somehow your cleanup is either missing or "not good enough". Such things happen for example when you initialise a stub/mock just *once* (before the first starts), but not *once* per test. Worst case, the dependency is *somewhere* (deep down) in your production code, for example a *static* field on some class that gets initialised when the first test is executed, causing problems when the second test "comes by".

For any more specific (code based) advice, you will have to share your tests, respectively a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll have a look at my static methods and companion objects now...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out a library I was using used a pseudo random seed each time it was run. It was only pseudo because the seed was still the same for each given run e.g.

**Run both tests together in intellij**

Test 1 seed used: 83

Test 2 seed used: 34

**Run both tests together in intellij again**

Test 1 seed used: 83

Test 2 seed used: 34

The seeds would always be 'randomly' allocated to the same numbers.

**If i ran each test individually it would go as follows:**

Test 1 seed used: 83

Test 2 seed used: 83

It was not possible to see this in any debug data.

The solution (to get consistent behaviour) was to set a specific seed every time before the method was run.